# How to remember text attributes in UITextView when the user starts typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I'm using a `UITextView` and I'm trying to have the text displayed using the `attributedText` property as the user types.

Here's my current code:

```
textView.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "",
    attributes: [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextLTPro-Regular", size: 12.5)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.colorFromCode(0x262626),
        NSKernAttributeName: 0.5,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
    ]
)
```

The problem is that if you supply an empty string, when the user starts typing, the text isn't being formatted with the `attributedText` properties.

However, I noticed if I supply a string, as the user begins to append that string, the text is formatted with the `attributedText` properties.

The only way I can think to accomplish what I need would be to override this function and set the text to attributedText everytime a user enters a key:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

Is there no other better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting an empty attributed string you need to use the `typingAttributes` property.

```
textView.typingAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextLTPro-Regular", size: 12.5)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.colorFromCode(0x262626),
    NSKernAttributeName: 0.5,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
]
```

See also the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/typingAttributes).

> The attributes to apply to new text being entered by the user.

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar with a UILabel? For example, I have a UILabel with no text in it, but as I parse my JSON I'm adding to text to it

Comment: @Thomas I'm afraid not. On a `UILabel` you have to use the `attributedText` property.